# Confuse about the size in mysql table fields

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just created one role table and i defined role_id tinyint(1), even though i was able to store 99, 200 max upto 255 as tinyint limit for unsigned. so then what is the meaning of passing this size in data-types?

when read little that, it is about the display width, but when i fetch result on my php page, it displays as they are stored in the table.

Any mentor, can you please guide me to clear it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [10.1.1. Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

```
M indicates the maximum display width for integer types. The maximum legal
display width is 255. Display width is unrelated to the range of values a type
can contain [...].
```

So `tinyint(M)`, or `tinyint(1)` in your case, means that any value stored in `role_id` will be chopped to a length of one byte when being displayed by MySQL. Similarly `tinyint(3)` would case a one digit integer to be padded with two spaces. You can also use `tinyint(3) zerofill` to pad with `0`s instead, but it has the side-effect of making your `tinyint`s unsigned.

However, regardless how you specify your `tinyint`s they will be stored internally as an integer in the range `[-128,127]` (signed) or `[0,255]` (unsigned), and so that's the value PHP will receive when querying your database.

You can use [mysql_field_len](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-len.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to limit the display width similarly with PHP.

Comment: salute to your answer. From head to toe, digested totally. Thank you so much.